# How to get the right blocks in Array Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, block, threshold

I have some code written in Matlab, I have matrix A 3 x 3. How can i get the number of blocks A > th, and save it in Matlab. And I just want to get a value next value "1" so I should get just 1 block is [1 2], is there anything wrong in my code? please help thankyou so much

here is my code

```
th = 0.1;
A =[1 0.2 0.03; 0.2 1 0.03; 0.2 0.03 1];
index = 0;

for i = 1:size(A,1)
    for j = 1:size(A,2)
        if i == j
            [i j] = find(A > th)
            index = index + 1;
            hasil = [i j];
        end
    end
end
```

The result if I run my program :
(1 1), (1 2), (2 1), (2 2), (3 1) ,(3 3)

Comment: What are your loops supposed to achieve? And you shouldn't overwrite loop indexes inside the loops (`i`, `j`).

Answer (score 1):

`ind2sub` can be used to convert the linear index to the subscript.

```
[hasilx,hasily] = ind2sub(size(A), find(A>th));
[hasilx hasily]

ans =

 1     1
 2     1
 3     1
 1     2
 2     2
 3     3
```

`find` can also directly return you the subscripts:

```
[hasilx,hasily]=find(A>th);
```

Comment: `[hasilx,hasily]=find(A>th);` gives the same result.

Comment: OP actually used `find` correctly in their question, so I'm not sure what the rest of their code does.

Comment: @David Yeah, now I look at it, the iterator is changed in the body of the for-loop. That behavior is pretty undefined. I actually mainly looked at the requested output.

Comment: Thanks, but I just want blocks [1 2] for the result. My code result still output [1 1] [2 2] and [3 3], I don't want value "1" come out.